# Как в ссылки карты sitemap, построенную с помощью Yoast SEO вписать priority и frequency?

Tags: php, wordpress, sitemap, yoast

Есть сайт на `Wordpress` с установленным **SEO** плагином [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/).
Меня интересует карта **sitemap**. На текущий момент структура карты при стандартных настройках такая:

```
<td><a href="http://example.test/post-sitemap.xml">http://example.test/post-sitemap.xml</a></td>
```

В [версии плагина 3.5](https://yoast.com/yoast-seo-3-5/) они пишут, что убрали *priority* и *frequency*, но мне их нужно вернуть для своей карты и сделать в таком виде:

```
<td><url>
<loc>http://example.test/post-sitemap.xml</loc>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>1</priority>
</url></td>
```

Для этого пробую через фильтр `wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_url` в **functions.php** сделать обращение к ссылке и вернуть измененную версию

```
function filter_wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_url( $get_permalink, $post ) { 
    if($post->post_type == 'page'){
        return $get_permalink . '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
    }
    return $get_permalink; 
}; 
add_filter( 'wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_url', 'filter_wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_url', 10, 2 );
```

но, по итогу дотягиваюсь только до самой ссылке и на выходе у меня получается

```
<a href="http://example.test/<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>">http://wp-credit7-ua.test/<changefreq>weekly</changefreq></a>
```

Как можно решить данный вопрос?

Answer (score 2):

Для изменения записи в сайтмап есть фильтр `wpseo_sitemap_entry`. Пример кода:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_entry', 'change_sitemap_entry', 10, 3 );
function change_sitemap_entry( $url, $type, $object ) {
    if ( 'post' === $type && 'my_custom_post_type' === $object->post_type ) {
        $url['chf'] = 'daily';
        $url['pri'] = 0.8;
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: получаю ошибку `Too few arguments to function change_sitemap_entry() , 1 passed in class-wp-hook.php on line 289 and exactly 3 expected`

Comment: в последней версии yoast seo можно передавать только 1 параметр `$url['pri'] = 0.8; $url['chf'] = 'daily';` но, на результаты самих ссылок это не влияет

Comment: @Вася 4-й параметр в добавлении фильтра укажите

Comment: @Вася насчет 1 параметра вы ошиблись! Там передавать можно все. А результат не обновляется ибо там кеш сайтмапа стоит. Вам нужно удалить весь кеш и если у вас нет редис/мемкеша то удалить из базы _transient_* для сайтампа

Comment: может быть мы друг друга недопоняли. Я в том смысле, что сама функция ваша работает и приоритет применяется, но внутри sitemap это не выводится. Как было, так и осталось `<td><a href="http://example.test/post-sitemap.xml">http://example.test/post-sitemap.xml</a></td>`

Comment: Транзиенты удалил по рекомендации плагина `add_filter('wpseo_enable_xml_sitemap_transient_caching', '__return_false');`